# Codeigniter - Check whether a Controller function exists or not, from the routes file

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, routes

Is there any way to check whether a **function** or **method** exists in a **controller** from **routes** file. I have tried as shown below, but stuck when the controller uses the **session** libraries which I couldn't add in the routes file.

```
$urlArr = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])));
$folderName = $urlArr[0];
$controllerName = $urlArr[1];
$actionName = !empty($urlArr[2]) ? $urlArr[2] : 'index';

include_once FCPATH."system/core/Controller.php";
include_once FCPATH."application/core/MY_Controller.php";
include_once FCPATH."application/controllers/$folderName/$controllerName.php";

// Here I need to check whether the function ($actionName) exists or not
```

**Note**: Don't suggest solutions to check the file as a string and check the function definition string exists or not.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have `Test` controller with `index` method:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'index';
    }

}
```

Since PHP >= 5.3 you can use callbacks in place of the normal routing rules. And to check if a method is defined you can use `ReflectionClass`. Here is a sample for `Test` controller:

```
$route['test'] = function()
{
    require_once FCPATH."system/core/Controller.php";
    require_once APPPATH.'controllers/Test.php';
    $rc = new ReflectionClass('Test');

    var_dump($rc->hasMethod('publicFoo')); // bool(false)
    var_dump($rc->hasMethod('index')); // bool(true)

    return 'Test/index'; // return your routing
};
```